Unable to set up the partitioning during Ubuntu 20.04 installation with Windows 11 dual boot
I am unable to see any partitions of my disk during Ubuntu 20.04 installation. Previously, I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and deleted that partition (300 GB), leaving it as free space. I also removed the GRUB bootloader from my EFI partition by following the steps mentioned here.
Now I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 for compatibility with certain software in our lab, however I am stuck at the partitioning step. I'm not sure what the problem is. I have attached screenshots of the disk partitions in in Windows 11 Windows Disk Management and the screen where I am usually stuck in the Ubuntu 20.04 installation process.
Windows Disk Management:

Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck here:

Screenshots of gparted and fdisk in an Ubuntu live session.



How old is system? If Windows 11, it may need newer version of Ubuntu to have kernel & drivers for newer hardware. Windows updates may have turned on fast startup or bitlocker so Ubuntu cannot see drive. You might be able to install a VM as it has its own drivers?

It is windows 11 and the system is new, I bought like 6 months ago. I tuned off the BitLocker part

you say that you attached two screenshots but it seems the one of where "I am usually stuck in the Ubuntu 20 installation process" is missing


https://i.sstatic.net/bZFm0FtU.jpg 2. https://i.sstatic.net/82pBlRKT.jpg 3. https://i.sstatic.net/8MNIQbpT.jpg


Tip: Try installing the Ubuntu you need on Windows WSL.
